# Can't get Scrapy to follow links

Tags: python, regex, screen-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website but I can't get scrapy to follow links and I don't get any Python errors and I see nothing going on with Wireshark. I thought it could be the regex but I tried ".*" to try to follow any link but it doesn't work either. The method "parse" does work though but I need to follow "sinopsis.aspx" and callback parse_peliculas.

Edit: Commenting the parse method gets rules working... parse_peliculas gets run, what I have todo now is change parse method to another name and make a rule with a callback but I can't still get it to work.

This is my spider code:

```
import re

from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from Cinesillo.items import CinemarkItem, PeliculasItem

class CinemarkSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'cinemark'
    allowed_domains = ['cinemark.com.mx']
    start_urls = ['http://www.cinemark.com.mx/smartphone/iphone/vercartelera.aspx?fecha=&id_theater=555',
                  'http://www.cinemark.com.mx/smartphone/iphone/vercartelera.aspx?fecha=&id_theater=528']


    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'sinopsis.aspx.*', )), callback='parse_peliculas', follow=True),)

    def parse(self, response):
        item = CinemarkItem()
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        cine = hxs.select('(//td[@class="title2"])[1]')
        direccion = hxs.select('(//td[@class="title2"])[2]')

        item['nombre'] = cine.select('text()').extract()
        item['direccion'] = direccion.select('text()').extract()
        return item

    def parse_peliculas(self, response):
        item = PeliculasItem()
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titulo = hxs.select('//td[@class="pop_up_title"]')
        item['titulo'] = titulo.select('text()').extract()
        return item
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since
>   the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic.
>   **So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer
>   work.**

http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/topics/spiders.html

Comment: Yes, I know that already. I was thinkin in renaming parser to parser_cinema but how could I call that method??

Comment: For each rule, you provide one callback method. You already did provide a callback method `parse_peliculas`. Just remove your `parse' method.